# How to get my import to work on jsp

Tags: jsp

I have looked at the other solutions, and i'm almost positive i'm just not piecing 2 and 2 together but anyways.  I'm  writing a jsp file and i want to import a class from one of my java files to this file, they are located in the same project and i'm working through eclipse.

My import line lookes like this (from my jsp file)

```
      <%@ page import ="pack.newDate;"%>
```

My java file looks like

```
package pack;
public class newDate
{
public static String getDate()
 {
     java.text.DateFormat date = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
     java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
 String dAt= " The time is " + date.format(today);
    return  dAt;
 }
 }
```

This fix is probably something simple and I apologize if i could derive it from a previous answer to a nearly identical question.

Comment: Are you seeing an error when accessing jsp? Also see for class naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: Sorry i meant to toss this in there (error code:Only a type can be imported. pack.newDate resolves to a package)

Comment: Update: I also got rid of the semicolon in the import line.... i don't know why it was there, the problem remains the same

Comment: Seems like you also have a package called pack.newDate

Comment: That is my package I'm trying to import it?

Comment: You have a class with the same name, if you want to import all classes in a package use pack.*;

Comment: It still tells me new date can't be resolved to a type

Comment: Is the class file present in a jar in WEB-INF/lib or as a .class file in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: All that's in the WEB-INF is my web.xml file

Comment: Ok buddy, you need to go through this first http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/a-simple-servlet-example-write-deploy-run/

Comment: I've already done that

Comment: If you defined it in the package you don't need to import it at all. You can just reference it like `pack.newDate.getDate()`

Comment: When I reference it that way I still get newDate can't be resolved to a type.

Answer (score 0):

I misnamed a folder, my apologies.